# i can"t get the country and wind speed from open weather api flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, openweathermap

```
class Country {
  final String country;

  Country({required this.country});

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final country = json['country'];
    return Country(country: country);
  }
}

class WindInfo {
  final double speed;

  WindInfo({required this.speed});

  factory WindInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final speed = json['speed'];
    return WindInfo(speed: speed);
  }
}

class WeatherInfo {
  final String description;
  final String icon;

  WeatherInfo({required this.description, required this.icon});

  factory WeatherInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final description = json['description'];
    final icon = json['icon'];
    return WeatherInfo(description: description, icon: icon);
  }
}

class TempratureInfo {
  final double temperture;
  final double humidity;

  TempratureInfo({required this.temperture, required this.humidity});

  factory TempratureInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final temperature = json['temp'];
    final humidity = json['humidity'];
    return TempratureInfo(temperture: temperature, humidity: humidity);
  }
}

class WeatherResponse {
  final String cityName;
  final TempratureInfo tempInfo;
  final WeatherInfo weatherInfo;
  final Country country;
  final WindInfo wind;

  String get iconUrl {
    return 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weatherInfo.icon}@2x.png';
  }

  WeatherResponse(
      {required this.cityName,
      required this.tempInfo,
      required this.weatherInfo,
      required this.country,
      required this.wind});

  factory WeatherResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final cityName = json['name'];

    final tempInfoJson = json['main'];
    final tempInfo = TempratureInfo.fromJson(tempInfoJson);

    final weatherInfoJson = json['weather'][0];
    final weatherInfo = WeatherInfo.fromJson(weatherInfoJson);

    final countryJson = json['sys'];
    final country = Country.fromJson(countryJson);

    final windJson = json['wind'];
    final wind = WindInfo.fromJson(windJson);

    return WeatherResponse(
        cityName: cityName,
        tempInfo: tempInfo,
        weatherInfo: weatherInfo,
        country: country,
        wind: wind
        );
  }
}
```

when i run a code that fetches information from open weather api it returns the country as Instance of 'Country' and the wind speed as Instance of 'WindInfo' rather then displaying the country name and wind speed while it does work on the description, icon, temprature, humidity and name.
please see the attached code that i have been using on my application.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cuz maybe you're trying to print the values as it is.
And by-default, the string representation of class is `Instance of 'Something'`

You can simply override this behavior by adding `toString` function in the class itself like

```dart
@override
String toString() {
  /// following line defines what you want the `toString()` to print
  return "Country(country: $country)";
}
```